# Firebase Realtime-database Doesn't Respond to HTML form contact submit

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, contact-form, tailwind-css

So i am new to firebase and tailwind but with a lot of work i made a landing page but the Contact and email updates forms i added just doesn’t work along. The data base is only taking Email Updates section and ignores the Contact in the database

There are no errors or anything.
When i put the Contact and press submit the data goes to Email updates section and just breaks!!!
If i remove the email updates section the contact works fine!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWafH.png)

Thats the Database!

```
<!-- Contacts -->
      <section id="Contacts" class="text-shark-100 bg-shark-500 body-font relative">
        <div class="container px-5 pt-24 pb-15 mx-auto">
          <div class="flex flex-col text-center w-full mb-12">
            <h1 class="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-white">Contact Us</h1>
            <p class="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">Have any Feedbacks & Questions, Just Go Ahead!</p>
            <p class="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">Also Get Email Updates.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="lg:w-1/2 md:w-2/3 mx-auto">
            <form class="flex flex-wrap -m-2" id="Contact">
              <div class="p-2 w-1/2">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="First Name" id="FirstName" type="text" required>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-1/2">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Last Name" id="LastName" type="text" required>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Company" id="Company" type="Text">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Email" id="Email" type="email" required>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <input class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Phone Number" id="PhoneNumber" type="tel">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <textarea class="w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none h-48 focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2 resize-none block" placeholder="Message" id="Message" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full">
                <button class="flex mx-auto text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 hover:shadow-2xl rounded text-lg" type="submit">Let's Talk</button>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2 w-full pt-8 mt-8 border-t border-shark-300">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- News -->
      <section id="News" class="text-shark-100 bg-shark-500 body-font">
        <div class="container px-5 pt-15 pb-24 mx-auto">
          <div class="flex flex-col text-center w-full mb-12">
            <h1 class="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-white">Get Early Access</h1>
            <p class="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">Subscribe to our emails & get notified about early updates.</p>
          </div>
          <form id="Subscribe" class="flex lg:w-2/3 w-full sm:flex-row flex-col mx-auto px-8 sm:px-0">
            <input class="flex-grow w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2 mr-4 mb-4 sm:mb-0" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" id="Name" required>
            <input class="flex-grow w-full bg-shark-400 rounded border border-shark-300 text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base px-4 py-2 mr-4 mb-4 sm:mb-0" placeholder="Email" type="email" id="EmailUpdates" required>
            <button class="text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 hover:shadow-2xl rounded text-lg" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Here is the HTML for the page!

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxx"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

// Reference messages collection
var contactRef = firebase.database().ref('Contact');

// Listen for a submit

document.getElementById('Contact').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();


  // Get values
  var firstname = getInputVal('FirstName');
  var lastname = getInputVal('LastName');
  var company = getInputVal('Company');
  var email = getInputVal('Email');
  var phone = getInputVal('PhoneNumber');
  var message = getInputVal('Message');

  // Save Contact
  saveMessage(firstname, lastname, company, email, phone, message);

  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('Contact').reset();

}

// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(firstname, lastname, company, email, phone, message){
  var newContactRef = contactRef.push();
  newContactRef.set({
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    company:company,
    email:email,
    phone:phone,
    message:message
  });
}
```

```
// Reference messages collection
var emailupdatesRef = firebase.database().ref('EmailUpdates');
  
// Listen for a submit
  
document.getElementById('Subscribe').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
  
// Submit form
function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get values
  var name = getInputVal('Name');
  var email = getInputVal('EmailUpdates');
  
  // Save Email Updates
  saveMessage(name, email);

  // Clear form
  document.getElementById('Subscribe').reset();
}

// Function to get form values
function getInputVal(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
  }

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(name, email){
    var newEmailUpdatesRef = emailupdatesRef.push();
    newEmailUpdatesRef.set({
      name: name,
      email:email
    });
  }
```

Here is the Javascript!

**Pls Anyone I don’t even understand what’s happening **

Comment: You need to trace the flow of data more closely. Use your browser's dev tools, in the "source" tab, to place breakpoints and examine what values are at various points. Or put `console.log` statements in your various functions. Is the data getting through `getInputVal()` correctly? Is it getting to `saveMessage()` correctly? If you find the point of failure, you'll have an idea of where the bug is.

Comment: i tried everything even the console.log and it works. There are so errors or anything everything works but the database takes the data from contact and puts it in the email updates section. I don’t get it why. If i disable the email subscribe part the rest works fine!

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a way to log db activity. In MySQL you can turn on the general log and see every query that hits it. If the problem isn't in your html and js (if it is submitting your form data correctly), the problem must be in your db layer.

Comment: I tried console.log through the steps but the js in not wrong.